# How do I insert asterisks to start a line of pmatrix other than the first?

Tags: amsmath, matrices

Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\begin{pmatrix}\\*\end{pmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

This produces () with no asterisk.  I find that if I do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\begin{pmatrix}\\**\end{pmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

then I get what I want.  Why is this so, and what is the correct way to get an asterisk as the first entry in the second line of a pmatrix?

Comment: `$\begin{pmatrix}\\\relax*\end{pmatrix}$`. ``\\`` is a command which has a starred form, so ``\\*`` is a variation of ``\\``, thus the first `*` is consumed. The `\relax` prevents ``\\`` from seeing the `*`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, what is the meaning of the stared double slash?

Comment: @Sigur Since ``\\`` is a command, it can be redefined (and it is, a _lot_). In this case, in a `pmatrix` (or other matrices, or in `tabular`) the `*` does nothing different. The starred for is just kept for compatibility with other usages of ``\\``. In plain text the `*` avoids a page break between the lines broken by ``\\``.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the `\\` command accepts a `*`-variant and an optional argument to add vertical spacing after the new line.

```
\\
\\*
\\[1ex]
\\*[1ex]
```

are all valid calls. The purpose of `\\*` is to avoid a page break. While it doesn't make sense to avoid a page break in the middle of a matrix (LaTeX would never do it), the syntax is kept in all situations.

However, in `amsmath` environments, placing the `*` on a different line than `\\` will not interpret the asterisk in the way explained above.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\begin{pmatrix} *\\*\end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{pmatrix}
* \\
*
\end{pmatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to input the matrix in one line, you have to somehow separate `\\` and `*`. A `\relax` will do, so

```
$\begin{pmatrix} *\\ \relax *\end{pmatrix}$
```

will print the matrix exactly as the second one in the image above. Blanks won't do, instead.

The same problem would present if you want to start a matrix row after the first with `[`.